# What do I need to add to my Google Script that checks if a file exists with a UI

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a script that will open a window and allow the user to enter a product SKU and have the script determine if the image is in a Google Drive folder. My code is here:

```
  function myFunction() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Enter product SKU to see if images are found',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    Logger.log(testfile(response.getResponseText()));// returns true if folder exists, false if it doesn't

    try {var testfile = DriveApp.getfile(fileName)}
  catch(err){exist=false}
  return ui.alert ('Item Found');
}
}
```

No response of any kind is received. First, and most importantly, how do I get a response. Second, how do I restrict the search to a user-defined folder? Finally, can it search and find if a SKU is part of an image title?
Sorry for any really frustrating, obvious errors, I'm new to Google Script.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [textbook example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs).

> First ... how do I get a response.

```
/*return*/ ui.alert ('Item Found');
```

You can't `return` that. I commented out all lines about `testfile()` as well, since you didn't include that, and it worked fine.

> Second, how do I restrict the search to a user-defined folder?

Use [`searchFolders()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFolders(String)) to get the folder, then [`folder.getFilesByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByName(String)) to get matching files within that folder.

> Finally, can it search and find if a SKU is part of an image title?

You could try [`folder.getFilesByType()'](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByType(String)) with an appropriate mimeType, then scan the resulting iterator for the file name.

If you're expecting particular file extensions on your image files, e.g. `SKU12345.jpg`, then the previous `getFilesByName()` can be used with the full name. The user could input the SKU, and you'd just build the rest of the name, then search. (We'd need to see more of your code and have more details to know for sure, but you have a starting point.)